# Iterate and take from vector of Options

Tags: rust

Every time I think I've got idiomatic Rust a little bit figured out, it defeats me again. In this case, I've got a struct `State` which contains, among other things, a `Vec<Option<Dude>>` called `ods`, where `Dude` is a struct that looks like this:

```
pub struct Dude {
    pub capacity: i32,
    pub status: DudeStatus,
}
```

What I would LIKE to do is define a function/method on `State` that iterates through `ods`. If a `Dude` is present in the given index (that is, `if ods[i] == Some(Dude)`), decrement his capacity by one, and if that causes `capacity==0`, remove the `Dude` from `ods`. Unfortunately, I seem to be running into type inference and/or ownership issues. Here's my attempt:

```
fn tick(&mut self) {
    for d in &self.ods {
        match d {
            Some(du) => {
                du.capacity -= 1;
                if du.capacity == 0 {
                    d.take();
                }
            }
            None => {}
        };
    }
}
```

However, this gives 3 compilation errors:

```
src/state.rs:40:18: 40:26 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&std::option::Option<dude::Dude>`,
 found `std::option::Option<_>`
 (expected &-ptr,
 found enum `std::option::Option`) [E0308]
src/state.rs:40                  Some(du) => {
                                 ^~~~~~~~

src/state.rs:46:18: 46:22 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&std::option::Option<dude::Dude>`,
 found `std::option::Option<_>`
 (expected &-ptr,
 found enum `std::option::Option`) [E0308]
src/state.rs:46                  None         => {}

src/state.rs:41:22: 41:32 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
src/state.rs:41                      du.capacity -=1;
```

The third error is easy enough to understand conceptually, but I'm not sure where I should be annotating the type. Type ascription is currently an experimental feature so I can't use `match d: Option<Dude>` which, to me, is the most intuitive. Additionally the other two errors suggest I have a borrow/reference error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code I used to fill in the aspects you didn't provide:

```
struct Dude {
    pub capacity: i32,
}

struct State {
    ods: Vec<Option<Dude>>,
}

impl State {
    fn tick(&mut self) {
        for d in &self.ods {
            match d {
                Some(du) => {
                    du.capacity -= 1;
                    if du.capacity == 0 {
                        d.take();
                    }
                }
                None => {}
            };
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

---

Checking out the first error:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `&core::option::Option<Dude>`,
    found `core::option::Option<_>`
(expected &-ptr,
    found enum `core::option::Option`) [E0308]

                 Some(du) => {
                 ^~~~~~~~
```

The `match` statement is looking for the match arm to be a `&Option<Dude`, but the pattern represents an `Option<_>` ("option of an as-yet-undetermined type"). If you change it to `&Some` or (more idiomatically) match on `*d`, that error will go away.

Then you run into an issue where you are iterating immutably, so that needs to be fixed (`for d in &mut self.ods` and `Some(mut du)`).

Then you are trying to move out of the vector into the `Some` pattern, so you need `Some(ref mut du)`.

Then you run into the **real** problem: you are trying to mutate the `Option` while referencing its internals. This is invalid and would lead to memory safety issues!

Instead, split up the concept of decrementing the count and removing the values:

```
fn tick(&mut self) {
    for d in &mut self.ods {
        let remove = match *d {
            Some(ref mut du) => {
                du.capacity -= 1;
                du.capacity != 0
            }
            None => false,
        };

        if remove {
            d.take();
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to remove from the `Vec`, you could also use `retain`:

```
fn tick(&mut self) {
    for d in &mut self.ods {
        if let Some(ref mut du) = *d {
            du.capacity -= 1;
        }
    }

    self.ods.retain(|d| {
        d.as_ref().map_or(false, |du| {
            du.capacity != 0
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Both answers were incredible. I'm tossing the checkmark to you for breaking down my boneheaded mistakes step by step. Thanks @Shepmaster! I had suspected that part of my issue was going to come from mutating the vec while iterating through it (changing Some() to None). I didn't even think about the fact that I was mutating the Option while I was still referencing its value!

Answer (score 4):

```
fn tick(&mut self) {
    for d in &self.ods {
```

This will give immutable `d`s. Since you want to modify `d` you should iterate on `&mut self.ods` instead.

```
        match d {
            Some(du) => {
```

Note that `d` is a reference. You should deference it `match *d`. And you want to capture `du` by mutable reference (`Some(ref mut du) =>`) so your changes will be propagated back to the original storage.

As the `None` arm is doing nothing you could use `if let` instead of `match` to save an indentation level.

```
                if du.capacity == 0 {
                    d.take();
                }
```

After we fixed the above two issues, the borrow checker will complain here. This is expected, as the borrow of `du` from `d` is still valid, but you now try to destroy `d`. We need to call `.take()` outside of the `match`. Personally I would add a flag to indicate if we need to nullify `d`. Note that since you are not using the result, simply calling `*d = None` is enough.

---

Final result:

```
fn tick(&mut self) {
    for d in &mut self.ods {
        let mut should_nullify = false;
        if let Some(ref mut du) = *d {
            du.capacity -= 1;
            if du.capacity == 0 {
                should_nullify = true;
            }
        }
        if should_nullify {
            *d = None;
        }
    }
}
```